# dayComponent in react-native-calendars not rendering : JDK issue?

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I was working on a react-native project using expo cli, in which i need to display a calendar. I was using the dayComponent property of the calendar to apply stylings to specific days as per the requirement and it was working fine. However I recently moved to react-native cli due to compatibility issues with another library. Since then the dayComponent property is not executing at all. In the below code, even the console.log is not executed.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Calendar } from 'react-native-calendars';
const App = () =>  {
  return (
    <Calendar 
    dayComponent={(e)=>{
      console.log(e);
      return <View><Text>{e.date.day}</Text></View>;
    }}
    />
  )
};

export default App;
```

One thing that i can think of, is that I have installed the latest jdk version. Which required me to do the following

1. add org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED to gradle.properties
2. add jcenter() under allProjects repositories in build.gradle

Could the jdk version be the problem? or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

it's the issue with the latest version of react-native-calendars, they have merged the PR to fix it about 1 hour before my answer. You can wait for new release or edit the version in `package.json`

from

`"react-native-calendars": "^1.1274.0",`

to

`"react-native-calendars": "1.1274.0",`

I assumed that you are using version `1.1274.0` like me